# QuerySet doesn't filter by user

Tags: django, django-queryset

Update:
Was made aware it might be due to some error in the authentication process. Here's my auth:

```
const LogIn = () => {
  let dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  // const auth = useAuth();
  const history = useHistory();

  const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(startLogin());
axios
  .post(
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login/",
    { username: username, password: password },
    { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } }
  )
  .then((res) => {
    const users = res.data;
    dispatch(LogInSuccess(users));
    localStorage.setItem("jwt", users.auth_token);
    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(users));
    console.log("users", users); // undefined
    history.push("/");
  })
      .catch((err) => dispatch(LogInFailure(err.message)));
  };
```

---

So my code is written in Django backend and React frontend.

For some reason, objects (in this case rats) aren't being filtered by the owner/user. I don't want to make permissions - anyone should be able to access someone else's rat, but in this specific list the user should only see the rats that belong to them.

Running other filters work, such as birthday. But when I try filtering by user, no rats show up. There's also no error. What could be wrong?

Object Serializer:

```
class RatSerializer(FlexFieldsModelSerializer):
    user         = serializers.CharField()
    body_colour  = BodyColourSerializer()
    eye_colour   = EyeColourSerializer()
    image        = ImageSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = rat
```

Views:

```
   class ratViewset(FlexFieldsMixin):
         serializer_class = RatSerializer
         def get_queryset(self):
            userid = self.request.id
            return rat.objects.filter(user = userid)
```

User serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('id', 'username', 'password')
```

And the JSON output for a user:

```
{
        "id": 13,
        "username": "new"
    }
```

In the JSON output for the object/rat, it clearly says which user it belongs to. So why won't the filter work?

Comment: Is it possible that ``self.requset.id`` is a string and the `id` field is an integer?  So you they do not match?  Maybe cast your ``self.request.id`` to an int?

Comment: Depending on your situation it might also be a good idea to use `request.user` rather than pulling a query param out of the request object. If it's supposed to be "show an authenticated user just their own objects" rather than "show the objects for user with id X, regardless of authentication". If it's the latter, I personally would probably make that ID part of the URL rather than a query arg. In part so I can use regexps in the URL declaration to ensure that I _can_ parse it as an int.

Comment: @saquintes That's possibly the case, how do I do that? (I'm a beginner)

Comment: @Peter DeGlopper Ohh, so you're thinking that instead of pulling a query param, instead your URL should be something like "/userID/objects"? That's a really good idea, then users will be able to view each others lists too. Not sure how to do that though as I'm new to this

Comment: I might do it as `/objects/<userId>`, but it's not a big deal and depends on the rest of the app. See the examples in the docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/#example - looks like the capabilities have advanced, you just need to declare `/objects/<int:userId>` or whatever you want and then your view will get an `int` parameter. Note that this is not secure at all, it's probably fine for your case because you said everyone can see everyone's data but there's nothing to enforce that the ID in the URL is for the current user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the new get_query which fixed the issue:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    user = self.request.user
    if user.is_anonymous:
        return rat.objects.all()
    return rat.objects.filter(user=user.id)
```

Basically I get the user first, and I filter by user.id. Earlier I tried to get the userId immediately and filter by that.

Another change I did was add ModelViewSet to the viewset, but I don't think that made a difference(?)

Edit: the `if user.is_anonymous` part just makes it so that the user sees all objects if they're not logged in. This is just for testing purposes

Answer (score 0):

If youre using:
`request.user`

Your user isn't authenticated.

Therefore it will return all.

Ensure you are logged in and try again

Comment: I am logged in, also tried logging out and in again. It doesn't show all objects -- it shows none :/

Comment: Yea but are you logged in though? Print `request.user` and make sure that the request has a user assigned. If it doesn't, then you aren't logged in to the API framework. Sometimes depending on how you register the views it can ignore the authentication mechanism. Usually when returning something other that a rest framework `Response` object.

Comment: How do I print request.user in JS? 

I posted my auth code, perhaps there's some error in there?